# How to keep data in UITableview after terminate the app in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a TableView in my application which retrieve data from MySql via PHP file.
Every time I will terminate (close) the application and restart it again it will start retrieving the data, which is poor way!

What I need to do is to load the last data which were in my UITableView before I retrieve the data from MySql. Let's say I have no internet connection then it will load the last data.

It is something like (Twitter and Instagram), those application will load the tables even you are not connected to the internet.

i have no Idea how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: you are supposed to download the data to your device and save it locally. Then load the data from the local file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save data in Core Data from your database pull.

In your viewDidLoad, if there is not connection, you can pull data from Core data instead of your web service.

For testing reachability of network, I reco using Ashley Mill's reachability class.

For learning about Core Data, there are a ton of tutorials online